# Get MVC Form Data Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following form using MVC :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Description)
        </div>

         <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Icon)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Icon, "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-pushpin.png", new { @checked = "checked" }) <img src="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-pushpin.png" alt="red pusphin" />
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Icon, "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-pushpin.png") <img src="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-pushpin.png" alt="blue pushpin" />
        </div>

    }
```

How can I retrieve the data using javascript?

I tried the following but it does not seem to be working:

```
document.getElementsByName('Title').value;
```

Comment: on binding control with model, browser will create id based on model, define your own id and access value using that id.

Comment: You mean get the data on form submit or on page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
document.getElementById('Title').value;
```

Check this fiddle

http://dotnetfiddle.net/t67Q3G

Comment: it is getElementById not Elements and I have tried already, the value being passed is ""

Comment: the fiddle worked as I was missing " " instead of  ' '

Answer (score 0):

Define ID for all controls as:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title,new{@ID="YOUR ID"})
```

Get value by id as:

```
$("#YOUR ID").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the values from the model to javascript you can simply do this.

```
function showpopup()
{
   var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
   alert(model.Title);
}
```